# save posted values to xml in php

Tags: php, dom, simplexml

```
<root>
  <gallery name="First"/>
  <gallery name="Second"/>
  <gallery name="Third"/>
</root>
```

I think I have solved part of a previous problem and now have the foreach loop correct? Still I can't get it to save the xml.

```
$objXML = new SimpleXMLElement(XML_FILE_NAME, null, true);  
foreach($objXML->xpath('/root/gallery/@name') as $key => $old){
    $new = $_POST['name'][$key];
    echo "$key : $old : $new<br />\n";
    $old = $new; // this does nothing??
    }
$objXML->asXML(XML_FILE_NAME);
```

**echo returns:**
0 : First : First New
1 : Second : Second New
2 : Third : Third New

Why does this not save the new posted values for 'name' back to my XML doc, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in a loop.

This mean each time the loop comes back to another *point* `$key` and `$old` get their respective new values.

I guess that's what you're trying to achieve (but I'm not you're sure I got your goal here)

```
foreach($objXML->xpath('/root/gallery/@name') as $key => $value){
    $new = $_POST['name'][$key];
    echo "$key : $old : $new<br />\n";
    $old = $value;
}
```

---

From your comment :

[You can test it here.](http://codepad.org/E6XOBDAi)

```
$objXML = new SimpleXMLElement(XML_FILE_NAME, null, true);  

$galleryLore = $objXML->gallery; // finding gallery
$i = 0;
foreach($galleryLore as $gallery){
  unset($gallery['name']); // We delete the old name
  $new = $_POST['name'][$i]; // We find the new name value
  $gallery->addAttribute('name', $new); // We add the new attribute we deleted before
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to replace the array of values from xpath (First,Second,Third) with the array of values from $_POST['name'] (First New,Second New,Third New). Then save these values back to xml.